# Passing multiple arguments in command line Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, command-line, arguments

I need to pass multiple arguments to maven command line to run a spring boot application. This is how I was passing command line arguments in spring boot. I am using spring boot 2.2.6 Release

> **mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--server.port=8999,--spring.application.instance_id=dhn"**

However I get the following error

```
nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'server.port' to java.lang.Integer

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'server.port' to java.lang.Integer:

    Property: server.port
    Value: 8999,--spring.application.instance_id=dhn
    Origin: "server.port" from property source "commandLineArgs"
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to java.lang.Integer

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Seems like the arguments are not parsed correctly

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The , separator seems not to work. Although I already saw this style in tutorials.

What works is a space as seprator:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments="--server.port=8999 --spring.application.instance_id=dhn"
```

Comment: Space separator does not work for me with Spring-boot 2.1.5

Comment: It seems space works from 2.2.x. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/18711

Answer (score 0):

For **`Maven Command-Line Arguments`** you can pass the arguments using `-Dspring-boot.run.arguments` without wrapping it in double quotes like:

> mvn spring-boot:run
> -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--server.port=8999,--spring.application.instance_id=dhn

For passing **`Gradle Command-Line Arguments`** first configure the `bootRun` task in `build.gradle` file as:

```
bootRun {
    if (project.hasProperty('args')) {
        args project.args.split(',')
    }
}
```

now pass the command-line arguments as:

> ./gradlew bootRun
> -Pargs=--server.port=8999,--spring.application.instance_id=dhn

Refer to this quick tutorial - [Command-Line Arguments in Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-command-line-arguments) for an extensive understanding.